# error appears saying cannot find the module '../util/http_util'

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm

I am trying to use node and notepad++ to create a website where a user can log in to it and it will save their details, giving them access to the site. I am experiencing a problem and I am really not sure why as everything thing looks fine in the code.
Below is a screenshot of the error and the code for it all.[

```js
/**
 * This is the dispatcher module for this example.
 *
 * It create a http web server and listen on port 8888.
 *
 * When client send request, it will dispatch the request to different module by request url path.
 */

var http = require('http');

var http_util = require('../util/http_util');

var home_module = require('./home');

var login_module = require('./login');

var register_module = require('./register');

var http_server_port = 8888;


/* This is the callback function which will be used by http web server.
*
*  This function will process client request.
* */
var http_server_callback_function = function(req, resp){

   // Parse query strings.
   http_util.getUrlParams(req, resp);

   // Get request url path value.
   var url_path = req.query_url.pathname;

   // Invoke different module's function by different request path.
    if(url_path === '/')
    {
        home_module.showHomePage(req, resp);
    }else if(url_path === '/login' )
   {
      login_module.showLoginPage(req, resp);
   }else if(url_path === '/check-login')
   {
        login_module.checkLoginAccount(req, resp);
   }else if(url_path === '/register')
    {
        register_module.showRegisterPage(req, resp);
    }else if(url_path === '/register-submit')
    {
        register_module.registerSubmit(req, resp);
    }else
   {
      resp.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
      resp.end("Request url is not valid : " + req.url.toString());
   }
}

// Create a http web server use above callback function.
var http_server = http.createServer(http_server_callback_function);

// Server is listen on port 8888.
http_server.listen(http_server_port);

// Print log data in console.
console.log('http server lisetning on port' + http_server_port);










// Require http_util module.
var http_util = require('../util/http_util');

/* This method will show home page with welcome message. */
exports.showHomePage = function buildLoginPage(req, resp, error_message) {

    var page_title = "Home Page";

    var page_menu = http_util.pageMenu();

    var page_content = "<font color='red'>Welcome to user register and login home page.<br/>Click above link to take action.</font>";

    // Generate home page with page template and special title, menu and content.
    var page_data = http_util.buildPage(page_title, page_menu, page_content);

    resp.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});

    resp.end(page_data);
}






/**
 * New node file
 */


var http_util = require('../util/http_util');

/* Return login form page to client request.

   This function is exported so can be invoked out side current module. */
exports.showLoginPage = function(req, resp){
   buildLoginPage(req, resp, '');
}


/* Verify user input login account data. Exported function also. */
exports.checkLoginAccount = function(req, resp){

   // Use node query string module to parse login form post data.
   var query_string = require('querystring');

   // If client use post method to request.
    if (req.method == 'POST') {

       var req_body = '';

        req.on('data', function (data) {
            req_body += data;

            // If the POST data is too much then destroy the connection to avoid attack.
            // 1e6 === 1 * Math.pow(10, 6) === 1 * 1000000 ~~~ 1MB
            if (req_body.length > 1e6)
                req.connection.destroy();
        });

        req.on('end', function () {

           // Parse post data from request body, return a JSON string contains all post data.
            var post_data = query_string.parse(req_body);

            // Get user name from post data.
            var user_name = post_data["user_name"];

            // Get password from post data.
            var password = post_data["password"];

            // If user name and password is correct.
            if(user_name === 'jerry' && password === 'dev2qa.com')
            {
                resp.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});

                // Assign page title.
                var page_title = "Login success";

                // Assign page navigation menu data.
                var page_menu = http_util.pageMenu();

                // Assign page content.
                var page_content = "<font color=red>User name and password is correct, login success.</font>";

                // Build login success page.
                var login_success_page = http_util.buildPage(page_title, page_menu, page_content);

                // Send login success page html source data to response.
                resp.end(login_success_page);
            }else
            {
               // If user name and password is not correct.
               req.user_name = user_name;
               req.password = password;

               // Return login form page back to response.
            buildLoginPage(req, resp, 'User name or password is not correct.')
            }
        });
    }
}


/* This is a private function which can only be invoked in this module.
*  This function is used to build login form page and return it to client.
* */
function buildLoginPage(req, resp, error_message) {

    http_util.getUrlParams(req, resp);

    var page_title = "Login Page";

    var page_menu = http_util.pageMenu();

    var login_form = "<h3>Input user name and password to login.</h3>";

    if(error_message!=='' && error_message!==null && error_message!==undefined)
   {
      login_form += "<font color=red>" + error_message + "</font><br/><br/>";
   }

   login_form += "<form method='post' action='/check-login'>" +
        "User Name : <input type='text' name='user_name' value='{user_name}'/><br/><br/>" +
        "Password :<input type='password' name='password' value='{password}'/><br/><br/>" +
        "<input type='submit' value='Login'/><br/><br/>" +
        "</form>";

    if(req.user_name==null || req.user_name==undefined)
    {
        req.user_name = '';
    }

    if(req.password==null || req.password==undefined)
    {
        req.password = '';
    }

    login_form = login_form.replace("{user_name}", req.user_name);

    login_form = login_form.replace("{password}", req.password);

    var login_page_data = http_util.buildPage(page_title, page_menu, login_form);

    resp.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});

    resp.end(login_page_data);
}






/**
 * New node file
 */


var http_util = require('../util/http_util');


/* Exported function which is used to display user register form page. */
exports.showRegisterPage = function (req, resp) {
    buildRegisterPage(req, resp, "");
}


/* Exported function also used to send a register success message to client. */
exports.registerSubmit = function (req, resp) {

    resp.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});

    var page_title = "Register Success";

    var page_menu = http_util.pageMenu();

    var page_content = "User info registration success.";

    var page_data = http_util.buildPage(page_title, page_menu, page_content);

    resp.end(page_data);
}


/* Private function that create and return user register form page. */
function buildRegisterPage(req, resp, error_message) {

    http_util.getUrlParams(req, resp);

    var page_title = "Register Page";

    var page_menu = http_util.pageMenu();

    var register_form = "<h3>Input user data to register.</h3>";

    if(error_message!=='' && error_message!==null && error_message!==undefined)
    {
        register_form += "<font color=red>" + error_message + "</font><br/><br/>>";
    }

    register_form += "<form method='post' action='/register-submit'>" +
        "User Name : <input type='text' name='user_name' value='{user_name}'/><br/><br/>" +
        "Password :<input type='password' name='password' value='{password}'/><br/><br/>" +
        "Email :<input type='text' name='email' value='{email}'/><br/><br/>" +
        "<input type='submit' value='Register'/><br/><br/>" +
        "</form>";

    if(req.user_name==null || req.user_name==undefined)
    {
        req.user_name = '';
    }

    if(req.password==null || req.password==undefined)
    {
        req.password = '';
    }

    if(req.email==null || req.email==undefined)
    {
        req.email = '';
    }

    register_form = register_form.replace("{user_name}", req.user_name);

    register_form = register_form.replace("{password}", req.password);

    register_form = register_form.replace("{email}", req.email);

    var register_page_data = http_util.buildPage(page_title, page_menu, register_form);

    resp.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});

    resp.end(register_page_data);
}






/**
 * This is the util module used by other module.
 */

// Require node url module.
var http_url = require('url');


/* This function will parse client request query string and passe out related query parameter and value.*/
exports.getUrlParams = function(req, resp){
   
   req.query_url = http_url.parse(req.url, true);
   
   console.log(req.query_url);
   
   req.user_name = req.query_url.user_name;
   
   req.password = req.query_url.password;
   
   req.email = req.query_url.email;
   
   req.mobile_phone = req.query_url.mobile_phone;
   
   req.home_phone = req.query_url.home_phone;
   
}

/* This function will return web page navigation menu html source code. */
exports.pageMenu = function(){

   var ret = '<a href="/">Home</a>';
   ret += '&nbsp&nbsp';
   ret += '<a href="/register">Register</a>';
   ret += '&nbsp&nbsp';
   ret += '<a href="/login">Login</a>';
   
   return ret;
}


/* This function will use input parameter to replace place holder in the page template file. */
exports.buildPage = function(page_title, page_menu, page_content){
   
   var page_template = "<html>" +
         "<head>" +
         "<title>{page_title}</title>" +
         "</head>" +
         "<body>" +
         "<table>" +
         "<tr><td>{page_menu}</td></tr><tr>" +
         "<tr><td>{page_content}</td></tr>" +
         "</table>" +
         "</body></html>";
   
   var ret = page_template;
   ret = ret.replace("{page_title}", page_title, "g");
    ret = ret.replace("{page_title}", page_title, "g");
    ret = ret.replace("{page_menu}", page_menu, "g");
    ret = ret.replace("{page_content}", page_content, "g");

   return ret;
      
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm6ha.png)

Comment: You also might want to look into express.js, it makes all this much easier for you.

Comment: replace: `exports.` to `module.exports`    also please add screenshot of app directory

Comment: ive tried everything in the queries and still cant get it too work and i am trying to do it using notepad++ as my application and im running it using node.exe request-router.js on cmd as admin

Answer (score 0):

Include your `http_utill` like below.

```
var http_util = require('./../util/http_util');
```